# Why + operator doesn't throw any exception when any null parameters?

Tags: c#, string, null

Sorry about my ignorance but I've been trying for a long time without a reasonable explication about this:
Why a `+` operator doesn't throw any exception when any parameter is `null`;
for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string str = null;
            Console.WriteLine(str + "test");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `string.Concat(...)` allows `null` parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because C# compiler translates `+` operator to [`String.Concat` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your operation and this method uses empty string `""` when you try to concatenate `null`.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> An Empty string is used in place of any `null` argument.

And from [7.7.4 Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is
>   `null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string
>   argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the
>   virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object. If `ToString`
>   returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

Also from [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55b2f6374a7cf7c1);

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0))
{
     if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
     {
         return String.Empty;
     }
     return str1;
}
```